# Gas apple syntax error

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu-assembler, keccak

I try to convert this assembly file : https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage/blob/master/SnP/KeccakF-1600/OptimizedAsmX86-64/KeccakF-1600-x86-64-gas.s into apple syntax. (old syntax)

I replace .eq by #define, .global by .globl, remove .type, .size.

There is some errors again (i use clang) :

1 --

error: invalid operand for instruction subq *25, %rsp
(the instruction is : `subq $8*25, %rsp` )

2 --

error in backend: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode :

`movb    KeccakPowerOf2(arg2), %al`

`xorb    %al, (arg1)`

with

`#define arg1 %rdi`

`#define arg2 %rsi`

and

`KeccakPowerOf2:
.byte   1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128`

3 --

error in backend: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode

`leaq    KeccakLaneComplementTable, arg5`

with

`#define arg5 %r8`

and

`KeccakLaneComplementTable:

```
.quad   0
.quad   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  //  1 be
.quad   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  //  2 bi
.quad   0
.quad   0

.quad   0
.quad   0
.quad   0
.quad   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  //  8 go
.quad   0

.quad   0
.quad   0
.quad   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  // 12 ki
.quad   0
.quad   0

.quad   0
.quad   0
.quad   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  // 17 mi
.quad   0
.quad   0

.quad   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  // 20 sa
.quad   0
.quad   0
.quad   0
.quad   0`
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X linking / relocation doesn't support 32bit absolute addressing.  Use RIP relative.

```
leaq    KeccakLaneComplementTable(%rip), arg5
```

---

For **2**, you probably need to load the base address with a separate instruction, before you index it with `movb`.  Any spare register will do.  I'll use `%rax` for example, since you're about to load into it anyway.  If you can spare a register, you can hoist the `lea` out and do it only once at the start.

```
lea     KeccakPowerOf2(%rip), %rax
movb    (%rax,arg2), %al
xorb    %al, (arg1)
```

Or if the offset between `KeccakLaneComplementTable` and `KeccakPowerOf2` is fixed, and that address is kept around permanently, then you can do

```
; if arg5 still has the address of KeccakLaneComplementTable
movb    KeccakPowerOf2 - KeccakLaneComplementTable(arg5, arg2), %al
xorb    %al, (arg1)
```

`KeccakPowerOf2 - KeccakLaneComplementTable` should be an assemble-time constant, and doesn't have to wait for link-time, so it's safe even on OS X.  The idea is that `[KeccakPowerOf2 - KeccakLaneComplementTable + arg5]` is `KeccakPowerOf2`, so `[KeccakPowerOf2 + arg2]` becomes `[KeccakPowerOf2 - KeccakLaneComplementTable + arg5 + arg2 ]`.

---

For **1**, IDK why `subq $8*25, %rsp` wouldn't assemble.  It assembles fine with GNU binutils 2.25.1.  Maybe try `$(8*25)`?  Or if you can't get that to work, just substitute the single number `$200` and put `200 = 8*25` in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for 3 and 1 it works. For 2 how can i do that ? ( i am not an assembly expert).

Comment: Yes thank you for you update. it compile now.i have to test it now . thank you